# Why is Finn's accent different from John Boyega's natural accent?

Tags: character, star-wars, the-force-awakens, the-last-jedi

There are several English actors in the new *Star Wars* trilogy: Daisy Ridley, Gwendoline Christie, and John Boyega, just to name a few.  Some of them use their normal accent, or something close to it.  However, for some reason Finn has an (American?) accent, rather than John's natural accent.  Why?

Comment: I assumed it was to show that he was always a Rebel...  It's always seemed to me that the English accents were always skewed heavily for the Empire/Sith and the American accents towards the Rebels/Republic, which pretty much keeps up with the American trope that people with English accents are bad guys.

Comment: @Taegost Kylo and Snoke have american accents...

Comment: Yeah, that's why I said "skewed heavily". I believe in-universe the it's all based on where they grew up, just like in the real world

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### He tried with a British accent first, and JJ Abrams said it didn't work.

Straight from the mouth of John Boyega himself in this interview on the Graham Norton show:

This pretty much settles the matter for John Boyega / Finn specifically. But for more about the **in-universe** significance of British and American accents in *Star Wars* generally, see the following Q&A from another SE site devoted to sci-fi and fantasy:

- [Where did the British accent originate from in Star Wars?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/152710/31394)
- [Why does Leia's accent change during A New Hope?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/2903/31394)
- [Is it true that most imperial officers have British accents?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/112449/31394)